# Is there any method to draw vector graphics for geometry in MSE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, images

I want to know if there is any kind of vector graphics tools like "Asymptote" or something like that in MSE. I would be very helpful for geometry problems. Or is is doable in MathJax?

Comment: Is this some you want to do, as opposed to making an image through whatever technique you prefer and then uploading it?

Comment: See also [Creating diagrams](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9632) and other questions [linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/9632).

Comment: The subset of $\LaTeX$ that MathJax supports is not very suitable for graphic illustration.   Away from Math.SE you might find support in some packages described by [this older TeX.SE post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-graphics-packages-are-there-for-creating-graphics-in-latex-documents).